# nlohmann json access nested value by single string

Tags: c++

I have a json like :

```
{
"answer": {
  "everything": 42
  }
}
```

Using [nlohmann json library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json) in C++, I can access at this nested value like this :

```
std::cout << my_json["answer"]["everything"];
```

I'm looking for a way to access it with something like :

```
std::cout << my_json["answer.everything"];
```

Comment: Why? The library designer picked the API they wanted to offer. You may need to write your own helper function.

Comment: In fact, I want to override value by passing argument at my program (e.g: ./my_bin --answer.everything=12)

Comment: So write your own function, that will split a string on a dot, and then call two `[]` with parts of the string.

Comment: Are you certain you'll never have a json key that contains a period?

Comment: @KamilCuk it's works for 2 nested keys but no more

Comment: @JohnFilleau a key could also contain `[]"'` so that’s not necessarily a problem if you think about a useful escaping strategy before.

Comment: @JohnFilleau I'm sure because I know my json content but I understand that we can legally have key that contain a period.

Comment: Just wanna make sure we hit the edge cases. Second the suggestion of a wrapper. nlohmann json doesn't work that way, so you'll need to roll your own.

Comment: @Furlings if you have a wrapper that doesn't work, show us the code and ask questions about that. Your question now boils down to, "How do I recursively call a function for each period in the input string" or something like that

Comment: `it's works for 2 nested keys but no more` what is "it"?

Comment: @Furlings I just modified my answer to have a proper setter as well and changed the getter to use pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't be possible to implement this with the syntax `j["name1.name2"]` you used. Many overloads for operators, including the bracket operators `()` and `[]` can only be declared inside a class. Furthermore `nlohmann::json` has already defined the `[]` operator to work like `j["name1"]["name2"]`! This means you would have to modify the library in order to achieve this precise syntax. But it seems you are only trying to have an arbitrarily nested Json and be still able to browse through it with a simple input string without necessarily sticking to the square bracket operator.

A simple solution is writing a **function `get(nlohmann::json, std::string)`** that takes an `nlohmann::json` as well as the corresponding dot-separeted names of the form `name1.name2.name3` etc. and returns the corresponding value. This can be achieved by splitting the string according to the delimiter and then calling the `nlohmann::json[]` operator to browse the Json string:

```
std::vector<std::string> split(std::string const& str, char const delim) noexcept {
  std::vector<std::string> res = {};
  std::size_t start {0};
  std::size_t end {0};
  while ((start = str.find_first_not_of(delim, end)) != std::string::npos) {
    end = str.find(delim, start);
    res.push_back(str.substr(start, end - start));
  }
  return res;
}

nlohmann::json get(nlohmann::json const& root, std::string const& dot_separated_names) {
  std::vector<std::string> const names = split(dot_separated_names, '.');
  nlohmann::json const* leaf = &root;
  for (auto const& name : names) {
    if (leaf->contains(name)) {
      leaf = &leaf->at(name);
    } else {
      // Error handling (e.g. throw error)
      std::cerr << "Name '" << name << "' not found!" << std::endl;
    }
  }
  return *leaf;
}
```

With the functions above you can achieve the desired output with `get(j, "name1.name2");`.

If you want to be able to **set** values as well you can similarly write a function `set`

```
nlohmann::json& set(nlohmann::json& root, std::string const& dot_separated_names) {
  std::vector<std::string> const names = split(dot_separated_names, '.');
  nlohmann::json* leaf = &root;
  for (auto const& name : names) {
    if (leaf->contains(name)) {
      leaf = &leaf->at(name);
    } else {
      // Error handling (e.g. throw error)
      std::cerr << "Name '" << name << "' not found!" << std::endl;
    }
  }
  return *leaf;
}
```

that can be called as `set(j, "name1.name2") = "value";`. It might be unintuitive to set a value like this so you might want to modify it to something like `template <typename T> set(nlohmann::json& root, std::string const& dot_separated_names, T&& value)`.
Probably it is even better to write this function for `std::vector<std::string>` instead of `std::string` and move the splitting of the string to a different routine. This way you can switch delimiter easily and can also browse through a Json just given a vector of names.

---

If you really wanted to use it as `j["name1.name2"]` you would have to write your own **wrapper class** for a `nlohmann::json` that defines the bracket operator in this way. But in this case you lose a lot of functionality of the wrapped `nlohmann::json` that you would have to supply by yourself, e.g. the other operators such as `<<` etc.

```
  class YourJsonWrapper {
    public:
      YourJsonWrapper(nlohmann::json const& j) noexcept
        : j{j} {
        return;
      }
      // Your custom bracket operator
      nlohmann::json const& operator [] (std::string const& dot_separated_names) const {
        // Get implementation (like above)
        // ...
      }
      nlohmann::json& operator [] (std::string const& dot_separated_names) {
        // Set implementation (like above)
        // ...
      }
      // Add the other operators you need and forward them to the underlying nlohmann::json

      nlohmann::json j; ///< The wrapped nlohmann::json
  };
```

Furthermore - as pointed out in the comments - using dot-separated strings could be **problematic** as a Json name itself might contain a dot as well. Therefore make sure your Json names can't contain dots by design.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's exactly what i was looking for ! I will implement it in my code and let you know ! Thank you :)